# Traversing from AppDelegate to other controllers

Tags: ios, swift

The hierarchy i am using is something as follows --- 
`UIViewController`->(present)->`UINavigationController`->(push)->`UITableViewController`. 
How can I reach to '`UITableViewController`' from my AppDelegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer...

```
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!
if let rootVC = window!.rootViewController {
            if let presentCont = rootVC.presentedViewController {
//presentCont  can be any controller in my case it's 'UINavigationController' from navigation controller I can get all the controllers.. 
//navigationController.viewControllers

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate` file

```
 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
 let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 var initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTable") as! UITableViewController //myTable is the storyboard id of your tableviewcontroller
 self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could firstly define a nil property in `AppDelegate`:

```
var referenceTableVC:UITableViewController?
```

Then in your `UITableViewContoller`, in the end of the method `ViewDidload()`, give the property the reference:

```
var targetDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
targetDelegate.referenceTableVC = self
```